# Uneven butt cheeks

Tags: strength, strength-training, lower-body-strength

I'm 15 years old and started lifting about 5-6 months ago. I started to lift because I wanted a booty and muscular legs. I have always been skinny so I am set on gaining weight in muscle. My right butt cheek has always been bigger than the left. Since I started lifting, I feel like it has become more noticeable. 
I'm not sure if the right is actually bigger or the left is just more lifted. I have read elsewhere that it could also be fat deposits and I have a slightly bigger right breast. Maybe the right side has more fat?

How can I fix it?
How long will it take?
Also any tips for lifting in general would be great.

Comment: Perfect body symmetry is (nearly) a myth. Everyone has minor differences between left/right. Unless you are grossly mismatched, it's a normal thing.

Comment: Do more isolation work on the buttock that is smaller.

Answer (score 5):

**Keep lifting normally!**

The worst thing you could do, is try to work the smaller buttcheek more than the other, because this will end up creating a whole new imbalance, rather than correcting your current one.

The best thing you could do, is work out like normal. Squats and lunges should be an integral part of your routine since you want to enhance the butt area.

As for the chest area, the same principle stands; keep lifting symmetrically. Don't overthink it. Don't force the issue.

Additionally, since you are 15 years old, you still have quite a bit of growing left to do, so all in all, chances are this is a self-correcting issue.

As for how long it will take, that's hard for any of us to answer, as we have very little information about your particular body. A physician or physical therapist would be more able to answer this.

If you need help setting up a workout program, there are a plethora of threads and websites for this, and of course, if you have any questions that don't seem to have been answered, feel free to ask!